# Mock private property with mockk throws an excpetion

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I'm using [mockk](https://mockk.io/) for my testing in kotlin. But I can't seem to override a private property in a spy object.

I have this object

```
private val driverMapSnapshotMap: MutableMap<Int, SnapshotImage> = mutableMapOf()
```

in a class that I spy on using

```
viewModel = spyk(DriverListViewModel(), recordPrivateCalls = true)
```

But when I try to make it fill up with mock values I get an error

```
every {
    viewModel getProperty "driverMapSnapshotMap"
} returns(mapOf(1 to mockkClass(SnapshotImage::class)))
```

The error I get

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is nearly impossible to mock private properties as they don't have getter methods attached. This is kind of Kotlin optimization and solution is major change.

Here is issue opened for that with the same problem:

https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/263

Comment: Yes, sorry for not updating but I ended up accessing the private properties myself through reflection

Comment: Ohhh, I see. It is sad to use reflection for such cases. But if you have no straightforward way of doing it, what can we do. I am happy you found "solution"

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to access private fields in Mockk for classes( for objects it is even simpler )

```
 class SaySomething {
    private val prefix by lazy { "Here is what I have to say: "}

    fun say( phrase : String ) : String {
        return prefix+phrase;
    }
}

  @Before
fun setUp() = MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)

 @Test
fun SaySomething_test() {

    mockkConstructor(SaySomething::class)
    every { anyConstructed<SaySomething>() getProperty "prefix" } propertyType String::class returns "I don't want to say anything, but still: "

    val ss = SaySomething()
    assertThat( ss.say("Life is short, make most of it"), containsString( "I don't want to say anything"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
every {
viewModel getProperty "driverMapSnapshotMap"
} returns mock(DriverRemoteModel::class)
```

Comment: "driverMapSnapshotMap" is a mutableMap, so I am returning a map object

Comment: Oh but now I see, I mock the wrong object here, it should be `SnapshotImage`

Comment: OK, changed it to the right object, but still no success