# Mockk Mocking Private Properties in Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockk

I have a simple class with a private field.

```kotlin
class EmployeeData {

    private var employeeAge: Int = 0
    
    fun getAge(): Int {
        return 1 + employeeAge
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this private `employeeAge` with the following from official docs

```kotlin
@Test
fun testPrivateAge() {

    val mock = spyk(EmployeeData())

    every {
        mock getProperty "employeeAge"
    } propertyType Int::class answers { fieldValue + 6 }
    every {
        mock setProperty "employeeAge" value any<Int>()
    } propertyType Int::class answers  { fieldValue += value }


    every { mock getProperty "employeeAge" } returns 33
    every { mock setProperty "employeeAge" value less(5) } just Runs

    assertEquals(10,mock.getAge())
}
```

I am receiving such exception from MockK

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.

at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.checkMissingCalls(StubbingState.kt:14)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.recordingDone(StubbingState.kt:8)
```

Any clue on what's I am doing wrong? Official docs suggest using such technique against private properties but for me it doesn't work and I'm using latest on this moment version of MockK which is **v1.10.0**.

Though for private methods it is working like a charm. I am able to test the private method in this logic.

Comment: This solution may work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65786951/3753943

Comment: Seeing this issue too!

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem with some Kotlin optimisations. According to MockK author "Brief explanation. It is nearly impossible to mock private properties as they don't have getter methods attached. This is kind of Kotlin optimisation and solution is major change."

More info can be found on these 2 Github issues:

- https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/263
- https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/104

Answer (score 2):

You can set a private property for your SUT using Java reflection.

```
val field = EmployeeData::class.java.getDeclaredField("employeeAge")
field.isAccessible = true
field.set(employeeData, 33)

assertEquals(34, employeeData.getAge())
```

Answer (score 0):

well I have the same issue and it seems like it's still not working - however I found a workaround by explicitly defining the setter and getter methods of the property and save the value in a private field. Imo this is very ugly and I don't think I'm going to use this (and rather skip the unit tests ): For example:

```
private var _myProperty = "Value"
private var myProperty: String
    get() {
        return _myProperty
    }
    set(value) {
        _myProperty = value
    }
```

Test:

```
every { sut getProperty "myProperty" } propertyType String::class answers { "some test value" }
```